# Error When i Re Enable Cache in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, error, cache

i Have Disabled The cache of magento before editing my store and when i try to re enable the all cache and try to visit my store i'm getting this error :

"There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1087169356159"

i have download the log file from var/log and this is the log :

```
{"0":"Item (Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Interceptor) with the same ID \"142\" already exists.","1":"#0 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/module-eav\/Model\/Entity\/Collection\/AbstractCollection.php(307): Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection->addItem(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Interceptor))\n#1 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/module-eav\/Model\/Entity\/Collection\/AbstractCollection.php(1123): Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Collection\\AbstractCollection->addItem(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Interceptor))\n#2 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/module-eav\/Model\/Entity\/Collection\/AbstractCollection.php(913): Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Collection\\AbstractCollection->_loadEntities(false, false)\n#3 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Category\/Collection.php(177): Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Collection\\AbstractCollection->load(false, false)\n#4 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Data\/Collection.php(831): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Collection->load()\n#5 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Plugin\/Block\/Topmenu.php(125): Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection->getIterator()\n#6 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\\Catalog\\Plugin\\Block\\Topmenu->beforeGetIdentities(Object(Magento\\Theme\\Block\\Html\\Topmenu\\Interceptor))\n#7 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Theme\\Block\\Html\\Topmenu\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#8 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Theme\/Block\/Html\/Topmenu\/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\\Theme\\Block\\Html\\Topmenu\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getIdentities', Array, Array)\n#9 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/Layout\/LayoutPlugin.php(71): Magento\\Theme\\Block\\Html\\Topmenu\\Interceptor->getIdentities()\n#10 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\Layout\\LayoutPlugin->afterGetOutput(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor), '\\n<script>\\n    t...')\n#11 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#12 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)\n#13 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Page.php(257): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getOutput()\n#14 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Layout.php(170): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page->render(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#15 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#16 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)\n#17 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#18 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)\n#19 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(139): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#20 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#21 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#22 \/home1\/lm1ym1u0\/public_html\/kwt\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#23 {main}","url":"\/kwt\/","script_name":"\/kwt\/index.php"}
```

and the store does not work until i desactivate all the cache
please i need your help

Comment: try reindex your magento project `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solution to solve this error.? please share the solution